# How to manage two different sounds using AVAudioPlayer in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

My requirements:
I have one title sound followed by 2 sec delay plays animation sound.  If i click the image play title sound and 2 sec delay play animation sound.  I had 39 images each and every images have title and animation sound.

Problem is: If i clicked first image it will play title sound and animation sound (2sec delay) .  In case i clicked first image it play title sound and i interrupt the sound when i click the second image it will play animation sound instead of title sound.  How to use interrupt function in AVAudioPlayer.

I tried this:

```
for(i=0; i <= [stgImageArray count]-1; i++)  {
    if(counter == i) {
        [self titleSound]; //title sound
        //animation sound
        [self performSelector:@selector(animationActionWithSounds) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f]; 
        [stgImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[stgImageArray objectAtIndex:counter]]];
        stgText.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [stgTextArray objectAtIndex:counter]];
        NSLog(@"%d", i);
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)stgImageArray.count);
    }
}
-(void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)s1player;
{
   [self.s1player pause];
}

-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)s1player;
{
   [self.s1player play];
}
```

Comment: Upon clicking the 2nd image it plays the animation sound of the first image or the second image?

Comment: second image .. i want the the order first title sound and animation sound of whole image set.